# ILogger log.Error method could not log Dictionary<string,string> or custom class in AppInsights

Tags: c#, logging, azure-application-insights

```
loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices);

try
{
    throw new Exception("This is a test exception for app insights.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.LogError(ex, "Exception message",new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"Controller","Error" } });
    throw;
}
```

I want to log error with this args, where args are dictionary. I log error but args didn't atempt in app insight.

Application insights allows custom object to be sent, but logger has issues about forwarding it to AppInsights. Simply it is not forwarded. Any idea?